# Rapid increase in n_lru_nuked objects in varnish cache with enough malloc to spare

Tags: cache, varnish

We are using varnish 3.0.3-3.5 on amzn ec2 and it is allocated around 3G of malloc. It starts with normal caching of object but when it hits a certain no of object+objecthead(around 14k), n_lru_nuked objects starts to increase rapidly and no of objects becomes saturated. Tried also with version 3.0.4-1 but didn't work. Please help me find the problem. Let me know if any other information is required.

Following is the setting:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a 0.0.0.0:80,:8980 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -s malloc,3G"
```

Stats info:

```
client_conn            1119377         4.89 Client connections accepted client_drop                  0         0.00 Connection dropped, no sess/wrk
client_req             7253764        31.69 Client requests received
cache_hit               276698         1.21 Cache hits
cache_hitpass           205516         0.90 Cache hits for pass
cache_miss             2478864        10.83 Cache misses
backend_conn            405876         1.77 Backend conn. success
backend_unhealthy         3421         0.01 Backend conn. not attempted
backend_busy                 0         0.00 Backend conn. too many
backend_fail              3938         0.02 Backend conn. failures
backend_reuse          6528731        28.53 Backend conn. reuses
backend_toolate          50598         0.22 Backend conn. was closed
backend_recycle        6579393        28.75 Backend conn. recycles
backend_retry             1351         0.01 Backend conn. retry
fetch_head              111720         0.49 Fetch head
fetch_length            216430         0.95 Fetch with Length
fetch_chunked          6486185        28.34 Fetch chunked
fetch_eof                    0         0.00 Fetch EOF
fetch_bad                    0         0.00 Fetch had bad headers
fetch_close              74820         0.33 Fetch wanted close
fetch_oldhttp                0         0.00 Fetch pre HTTP/1.1 closed
fetch_zero                   0         0.00 Fetch zero len
fetch_failed                17         0.00 Fetch failed
fetch_1xx                    0         0.00 Fetch no body (1xx)
fetch_204                    0         0.00 Fetch no body (204)
fetch_304                 9986         0.04 Fetch no body (304)
n_sess_mem                 107          .   N struct sess_mem
n_sess                      37          .   N struct sess
n_object                  4373          .   N struct object
n_vampireobject              0          .   N unresurrected objects
n_objectcore              4384          .   N struct objectcore
n_objecthead              8041          .   N struct objecthead
n_waitinglist             3180          .   N struct waitinglist
n_vbc                       75          .   N struct vbc
n_wrk                       41          .   N worker threads
n_wrk_create              1585         0.01 N worker threads created
n_wrk_failed                 0         0.00 N worker threads not created
n_wrk_max                    0         0.00 N worker threads limited
n_wrk_lqueue                 0         0.00 work request queue length
n_wrk_queued             12335         0.05 N queued work requests
n_wrk_drop                   0         0.00 N dropped work requests
n_backend                   34          .   N backends
n_expired               501853          .   N expired objects
n_lru_nuked            1972544          .   N LRU nuked objects
n_lru_moved             249223          .   N LRU moved objects
losthdr                      0         0.00 HTTP header overflows
n_objsendfile                0         0.00 Objects sent with sendfile
n_objwrite             7072900        30.90 Objects sent with write
n_objoverflow                0         0.00 Objects overflowing workspace
s_sess                 1119369         4.89 Total Sessions
s_req                  7253764        31.69 Total Requests
s_pipe                   39412         0.17 Total pipe
s_pass                 4421895        19.32 Total pass
s_fetch                6899124        30.14 Total fetch
s_hdrbytes          3244163451     14174.64 Total header bytes
s_bodybytes        54294899374    237229.27 Total body bytes
sess_closed             275785         1.20 Session Closed
sess_pipeline                2         0.00 Session Pipeline
sess_readahead               3         0.00 Session Read Ahead
sess_linger            7181910        31.38 Session Linger
sess_herd              3441115        15.04 Session herd
shm_records          662367830      2894.07 SHM records
shm_writes            31444934       137.39 SHM writes
shm_flushes                  1         0.00 SHM flushes due to overflow
shm_cont                  5840         0.03 SHM MTX contention
shm_cycles                 325         0.00 SHM cycles through buffer
sms_nreq                 32172         0.14 SMS allocator requests
sms_nobj                     0          .   SMS outstanding allocations
sms_nbytes                   0          .   SMS outstanding bytes
sms_balloc            12256989          .   SMS bytes allocated
sms_bfree             12256989          .   SMS bytes freed
backend_req            6900427        30.15 Backend requests made
n_vcl                        1         0.00 N vcl total
n_vcl_avail                  1         0.00 N vcl available
n_vcl_discard                0         0.00 N vcl discarded
n_ban                        1          .   N total active bans
n_ban_gone                   1          .   N total gone bans
n_ban_add                    1         0.00 N new bans added
n_ban_retire                 0         0.00 N old bans deleted
n_ban_obj_test               0         0.00 N objects tested
n_ban_re_test                0         0.00 N regexps tested against
n_ban_dups                   0         0.00 N duplicate bans removed
hcb_nolock             2961085        12.94 HCB Lookups without lock
hcb_lock               2464684        10.77 HCB Lookups with lock
hcb_insert             2464679        10.77 HCB Inserts
esi_errors                   0         0.00 ESI parse errors (unlock)
esi_warnings                 0         0.00 ESI parse warnings (unlock)
accept_fail                  0         0.00 Accept failures
client_drop_late             0         0.00 Connection dropped late
uptime                  228871         1.00 Client uptime
dir_dns_lookups              0         0.00 DNS director lookups
dir_dns_failed               0         0.00 DNS director failed lookups
dir_dns_hit                  0         0.00 DNS director cached lookups hit
dir_dns_cache_full           0         0.00 DNS director full dnscache
vmods                        0          .   Loaded VMODs
n_gzip                       0         0.00 Gzip operations
n_gunzip               5852234        25.57 Gunzip operations
LCK.sms.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sms.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sms.locks            96516         0.42 Lock Operations
LCK.sms.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.smp.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smp.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smp.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.smp.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.sma.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sma.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sma.locks         21844471        95.44 Lock Operations
LCK.sma.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.smf.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.smf.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.smf.locks         14105325        61.63 Lock Operations
LCK.smf.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hsl.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hsl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hsl.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hsl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hcb.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcb.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcb.locks          4926255        21.52 Lock Operations
LCK.hcb.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.hcl.creat                0         0.00 Created locks
LCK.hcl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.hcl.locks                0         0.00 Lock Operations
LCK.hcl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vcl.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vcl.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vcl.locks             6438         0.03 Lock Operations
LCK.vcl.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.stat.creat               1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.stat.destroy             0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.stat.locks         1119443         4.89 Lock Operations
LCK.stat.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.sessmem.creat            1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.sessmem.destroy            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.sessmem.locks        1136901         4.97 Lock Operations
LCK.sessmem.colls              0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.wstat.creat                1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wstat.destroy              0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wstat.locks           499424         2.18 Lock Operations
LCK.wstat.colls                0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.herder.creat               1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.herder.destroy             0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.herder.locks           12215         0.05 Lock Operations
LCK.herder.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.wq.creat                   2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.wq.destroy                 0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.wq.locks             7893519        34.49 Lock Operations
LCK.wq.colls                   0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.objhdr.creat         2465018        10.77 Created locks
LCK.objhdr.destroy       2457038        10.74 Destroyed locks
LCK.objhdr.locks        16808877        73.44 Lock Operations
LCK.objhdr.colls               0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.exp.creat                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.exp.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.exp.locks            5182011        22.64 Lock Operations
LCK.exp.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.lru.creat                  2         0.00 Created locks
LCK.lru.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.lru.locks            4451317        19.45 Lock Operations
LCK.lru.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.cli.creat                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.cli.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.cli.locks              76262         0.33 Lock Operations
LCK.cli.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.ban.creat                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.ban.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.ban.locks            5182052        22.64 Lock Operations
LCK.ban.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vbp.creat                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbp.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbp.locks            3155814        13.79 Lock Operations
LCK.vbp.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.vbe.creat                  1         0.00 Created locks
LCK.vbe.destroy                0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.vbe.locks             819553         3.58 Lock Operations
LCK.vbe.colls                  0         0.00 Collisions
LCK.backend.creat             34         0.00 Created locks
LCK.backend.destroy            0         0.00 Destroyed locks
LCK.backend.locks       14391476        62.88 Lock Operations
LCK.backend.colls              0         0.00 Collisions
SMF.s0.c_req             6836951        29.87 Allocator requests
SMF.s0.c_fail            1972544         8.62 Allocator failures
SMF.s0.c_bytes      327625674752   1431486.19 Bytes allocated
SMF.s0.c_freed      327564849152   1431220.42 Bytes freed
SMF.s0.g_alloc              8403          .   Allocations outstanding
SMF.s0.g_bytes          60825600          .   Bytes outstanding
SMF.s0.g_space          44032000          .   Bytes available
SMF.s0.g_smf                8805          .   N struct smf
SMF.s0.g_smf_frag            402          .   N small free smf
SMF.s0.g_smf_large             0          .   N large free smf
SMA.Transient.c_req      8848148        38.66 Allocator requests
SMA.Transient.c_fail           0         0.00 Allocator failures
SMA.Transient.c_bytes 564174348191   2465032.04 Bytes allocated
SMA.Transient.c_freed 564174332082   2465031.97 Bytes freed
SMA.Transient.g_alloc           10          .   Allocations outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_bytes        16109          .   Bytes outstanding
SMA.Transient.g_space            0          .   Bytes available
```

Comment: How is your varnish cache usage over time? An increasing `n_lru_nuked` indicates that you're running out of storage or memory allocated for cache (http://serverfault.com/a/441763/47016)